# PNG Truecolor with tRNS Chunk

Tags: png

I would like to confirm my interpretation of the PNG file format description is correct with color type 0x02 and with tRNS chunk present. It says on PNG website that:

> For colour types 0 or 2, two bytes per sample are used regardless of the image bit depth (see 7.1: Integers and byte order). Pixels of the specified grey sample value or RGB sample values are treated as transparent (equivalent to alpha value 0); all other pixels are to be treated as fully opaque (alpha value 2bitdepth-1). If the image bit depth is less than 16, the least significant bits are used and the others are 0.

Give this same tRNS Chunk:

```
Length: 6
Type: tRNS
Data: 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff 
CRC: 37581b7d
```

Does this mean for RRGGGBBB: 0xFFFFFF or the white color is treated as transparent and all other colors are as is? If so, for the general case, I need to construct an array of such color (say array of int) and during the decoding of the IDAT chunk, I need to look up if the color is one of the transparent color, if so, it is treated as (RRGGBBAA) 0xRRGGBB00, or fully transparent? What would  be a good LUT for such case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

> I need to look up if the color is one of the transparent color,

Actually not "one of" but *the* transparent colour: in the truecolor+TRNS scenario all colors are opaque except one.

> What would be a good LUT for such case?

I don't think that scenario has to do with LUTs. Think of this format as an efficient way to store a true color image with "hard" (yes/no) transparency. The decoder will typically either decode the image adding an alpha channel (and then the colour would be factually ignored), (for example you can see [lineToARGB32](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/source/browse/src/main/java/ar/com/hjg/pngj/ImageLineHelper.java) method here)  or either by ignoring the TRNS.

Notice that this truecolour+TRNS case is not very usual, there are not many PNG images with that format, and many readers just ignore the TRNS in that case.